# python 3.3.2 do I get the right understanding of the function "round"?

Tags: python, rounding

Sorry, but I really don't know what's the meaning of the defination of `round` in python 3.3.2 doc:

> `round(number[, ndigits])`
>   Return the floating point value *number* rounded to *ndigits* digits after the decimal point. If *ndigits* is omitted, it defaults to zero. Delegates to `number.__round__(ndigits)`.
>
> For the built-in types supporting `round()`, values are rounded to the closest multiple of 10 to the power minus *ndigits* if two multiples are equally close, rounding is done toward the even choice (so, for example, both `round(0.5)` and `round(-0.5)` are `0`, and `round(1.5)` is `2`). The return value is an integer if called with one argument, otherwise of the same type as *number*.

I don't know how come the *multiple of 10* and `pow`.

After reading the following examples, I think `round(number,n)` works like:

if let `number` be `123.456`, let `n` be `2`

1. `round` will get two number:`123.45` and `123.46`
2. `round` compares `abs(number-123.45)` (0.006) and `abs(number-123.46)` (0.004),and chooses the smaller one.
3. so, `123.46` is the result.

and if let `number` be `123.455`, let `n` be `2`:

1. `round` will get two number:`123.45` and `123.46`
2. `round` compares `abs(number-123.45)` (0.005) and `abs(number-123.46)` (0.005). They are equal. So `round` checks the last digit of `123.45` and `123.46`. The even one is the result.
3. so, the result is `123.46`

Am I right?

If not, could you offer a understandable version of *values are rounded to the closest multiple of 10 to the power minus ndigits*?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
ndigits = 0 => pow(10, -ndigits) = 10^(-ndigits) = 1
ndigits = 1 => pow(10, -ndigits) = 10^(-ndigits) = 0.1
etc.

>>> for ndigits in range(6):
...     print round(123.456789, ndigits) / pow(10, -ndigits)
123.0
1235.0
12346.0
123457.0
1234568.0
12345679.0
```

Basically, the number you get is always an integer multiple of 10^(-ndigits). For ndigits=0, that means the number you get is itself an integer, for ndigits=1 it means it won't have more than one non-zero value after the decimal point.

Comment: thanks. Now I know the `multiple` must be an integer. and `10 to the power minus ndigits` means pow(10, -ndigits).

Comment: round(2.5)  you will have 2 options 3.0 or 2.0 , rounding is done toward the even choice , that's why we get 2.0 ,

Answer (score 2):

It helps to know that anything to the power of 0 equals 1. As ndigits increases, the function:

`f(ndigits) = 10-ndigits` gets smaller as you increase ndigits. Specifically as you increase ndigits by 1, you simply shift the decimal place of precision one left. e.g. `10^-0 = 1`, `10^-1 = .1` and `10^-2 = .01`. The place where the 1 is in the answer is the last point of precision for `round`.

For the part where it says

> For the built-in types supporting round(), values are rounded to the
>   closest multiple of 10 to the power minus ndigits; if two multiples
>   are equally close, rounding is done toward the even choice (so, for
>   example, both round(0.5) and round(-0.5) are 0, and round(1.5) is 2).

This has unexpected behavior in Python 3 and it will *not* work for all floats. Consider the example you gave, `round(123.455, 2)` yields the value 123.45. This is *not* expected behavior because the closest even multiple of `10^-2` is `123.46`, not `123.45`!

To understand this, you have to pay special attention to the note below this:

> Note The behavior of round() for floats can be surprising: for
>   example, round(2.675, 2) gives 2.67 instead of the expected 2.68. This
>   is not a bug: it’s a result of the fact that most decimal fractions
>   can’t be represented exactly as a float.

And that is why certain floats will round to the "wrong value" and there is really no easy workaround as far as I am aware. (sadface) You could use fractions (i.e. two variables representing the numerator and the denominator) to represent floats in a custom round function if you want to get different behavior than the unpredictable behavior for floats.

Comment: Thanks for the "unexpected behavior".